# H2 database CSVREAD and date convert

Tags: sql, database, h2

A H2 database and `leave` table. I try to insert records from a CSV file with :

```
INSERT INTO LEAVE (date,city,days,total) SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('C:\path\SAMPLE.csv',null);
```

The error is

Cannot parse "DATE" constant "29/06/2018"; SQL statement:

The CSV data is similar to:

`date,city,days,total
30/06/2019,los angeles, 245.2, 34708.2
12/04/2019.san deigo, 234.1, 45708.4
02/05/2019,san francisco, 765.4, 56087.2`

The table schema is similar to:

`id,date,city,days,total
1,2019-06-30,los angeles, 245.2, 34708.2`

How would I include a CONVERT statement to yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: May be the database expects a `;`as data limiter. Another thing is, your csv file contains only three columns, the database has fore.

Answer (score 0):

Working:

```
INSERT INTO LEAVE (DATE,CITY) SELECT "AREA",parsedatetime("DATE",'d/M/y') FROM CSVREAD('C:\PATH\SAMPLE.csv',null);
```